# Overlay views one by one in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have the following code with a struct and two views. On tap of the firstScreenOverlay button i want to show the secondScreenOverlay and hide the previous one and so on. Any help appreciated!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Text("hello there")
         .overlay(firstScreenOverlay, alignment: .center)
    }

}


private var firstScreenOverlay: some View {

        ZStack {
            
            Color.blue
                .opacity(0.5)

                Button {} label: {
                    Text("Next")
                        .fullWidth()
                }
}
}

private var secondScreenOverlay: some View {

        ZStack {
            
            Color.red
                .opacity(0.5)
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a way to keep track of what is showing. You can use a variable and an `enum`

```
import SwiftUI

struct DynamicOverlay: View {
    //Keeps track of what is showing
    @State var selectedOverlay: OverlayViews = .none
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("hello there")
            //Button changes what is being displayed
            Button("first", action: {
                selectedOverlay = .first
            })
        }
        //Displays the selected view
        .overlay(selectedOverlay.view($selectedOverlay), alignment: .center)
    }
    
}

enum OverlayViews{
    case first
    case second
    case none
    //Holds all the options for the views
    @ViewBuilder func view(_ selectedView: Binding<OverlayViews>) -> some View{
        switch self{
        case .first:
            ZStack {
                Color.blue
                    .opacity(0.5)
                
                Button {
                    selectedView.wrappedValue = .second
                } label: {
                    Text("Next")
                }
            }
        case .second:
            ZStack {
                
                Color.red
                    .opacity(0.5)
                Button("home") {
                    selectedView.wrappedValue = .none
                }
            }
        case .none:
            EmptyView()
            
        }
    }
}


struct DynamicOverlay_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DynamicOverlay()
    }
}
```