# How to not show the overlay image after navigating to new view in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a button for an SF symbol that does a swiping animation effect in .overlay() so it stays at the top, but after I navigate to another View the SF symbol is still there. I wonder how I can have the view reset before going to a new View or have the .overlay unshow after navigating.
structure is something like this

```
    var body: some View{
      NavigationView{
         NavigationLink{
             destination: WelcomeScreenView()
         }
      }
      .overlay(
        Button(action:{}, label:{
           Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
             .gesture(
               DragGesture() 
               // the animation goes here
             )
        }
      )
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overlay views one by one in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960717/overlay-views-one-by-one-in-swiftui)

Comment: @loremipsum thanks for attaching this post, I see he has a button going to another view, and included the case in enum, if I have to go to another view(a different swiftui file) how would I include that in the case if I were to use this method?

Comment: You can use onAppear of the destination to set none

Comment: onAppear in the destination view to have it set to None? I have this swiftui view called welcomescreenview that is my destination, how can I make it that onappear sets to none?