# Open sheet and overwrite current sheet or provide internal navigationstack inside sheet

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I have a button as shown below:

```
private var getStartedButton: some View {
    Button {
        showGetStartedSheet.toggle()
    } label: {
        Text("Get Started")
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showGetStartedSheet) {
        LoginUserSheetView()
            .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.70), .large])
    }
}
```

Which opens the `LoginUserSheetView()` view and has the following function inside:

```
private var userCreateAccount: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .center) {
        Text("New MapGliders? User register")
            .sheet(isPresented: $showUserRegisterSheet) {
                RegisterUserSheetView()
                    .presentationDetents([.fraction(0.70), .large])
            }
    }
}
```

The above code, then opens another sheet which presents the following code:

```
private var appleButton: some View {
    Button {
        // Hello
    } label: {
        HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
            Image(systemName: "applelogo")
            Text("Hello")
        }
    }
}
```

The above code (lots has been removed) produces the following output:

https://im4.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-4-4ecfdb6d55.gif

As you can see the video above, the second sheet opens on top of the old sheet, I would like the sheet to be overwritten or create a navigation on a single sheet.

Does anyone know how I can close `LoginUserSheetView()` when `RegisterUserSheetView()` is opened? or how could I make the sheet be overwritten or even use a navigation to navigate to `RegisterUserSheetView()` when on the `LoginUserSheetView()` is opened.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overlay views one by one in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960717/overlay-views-one-by-one-in-swiftui)

Comment: @loremipsum, this looks promising but it doesn't involve anything with sheets.

Comment: Same concept you can replace the content of the sheet with it instead of overlay or use “.sheet(item:)”

Comment: @loremipsum - Ohh interesting, I didn't know that - I will have to look into this.

Comment: @loremipsum, do you have an example on how .sheet can replace `.overlay(selectedOverlay.view($selectedOverlay), alignment: .center)` in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option is to use `sheet(item:)`. But this does dismiss the sheet and they makes it reappear with the new value

```
struct DynamicOverlay: View {
    @State var selectedOverlay: OverlayViews? = nil
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("hello there")
            Button("first", action: {
                selectedOverlay = .first
            })
            
        }
        .sheet(item: $selectedOverlay){ passed in
            passed.view($selectedOverlay)
        }
    }
    enum OverlayViews: String, Identifiable{
        var id: String{
            rawValue
        }
        case first
        case second
        
        @ViewBuilder func view(_ selectedView: Binding<OverlayViews?>) -> some View{
            switch self{
            case .first:
                ZStack {
                    Color.blue
                        .opacity(0.5)
                    
                    Button {
                        selectedView.wrappedValue = .second
                    } label: {
                        Text("Next")
                    }
                }
            case .second:
                ZStack {
                    
                    Color.red
                        .opacity(0.5)
                    Button("home") {
                        selectedView.wrappedValue = nil
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second option doesn't have the animation behavior but required a small "middle-man" `View`

```
import SwiftUI

struct DynamicOverlay: View {
    @State var selectedOverlay: OverlayViews = .none
    @State var presentSheet: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("hello there")
            Button("first", action: {
                selectedOverlay = .first
                presentSheet = true
            })
            
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $presentSheet){
            //Middle-main
            UpdatePlaceHolder(selectedOverlay: $selectedOverlay)
        }
    }
    enum OverlayViews{
        case first
        case second
        case none
        
        @ViewBuilder func view(_ selectedView: Binding<OverlayViews>) -> some View{
            switch self{
            case .first:
                ZStack {
                    Color.blue
                        .opacity(0.5)
                    
                    Button {
                        selectedView.wrappedValue = .second
                    } label: {
                        Text("Next")
                    }
                }
            case .second:
                ZStack {
                    
                    Color.red
                        .opacity(0.5)
                    Button("home") {
                        selectedView.wrappedValue = .none
                    }
                }
            case .none:
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
    }
    //Needed to reload/update the selected item on initial presentation
    struct UpdatePlaceHolder: View {
        @Binding var selectedOverlay: OverlayViews
        
        var body: some View{
            selectedOverlay.view($selectedOverlay)
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

You can read a little more on why you need that intermediate view here [SwiftUI: Understanding .sheet / .fullScreenCover lifecycle when using constant vs @Binding initializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65281559/swiftui-understanding-sheet-fullscreencover-lifecycle-when-using-constant-v/65281850#65281850)

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks for the explanation! I learned something new with this