# SwiftUI switch function without AnyView

Tags: swiftui

I learned that I shouldn't be using `AnyView()` in SwiftUI. I have written many functions with switch statements to return corresponding Views like the below code. I'm trying to learn the best way to migrate the switch statements away from `AnyView()`

```
struct T01: View{
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            showView(i: 1)
        }
    }
    
    func showView(i: Int) -> some View{
        switch(i){
            case 0: return AnyView(viewOne)
            case 1: return AnyView(viewTwo)
            default: return AnyView(EmptyView())
        }
    }
    
    var viewOne: some View {
        Text("View One")
    }
    
    var viewTwo: some View {
        Text("View Two")
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overlay views one by one in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73960717/overlay-views-one-by-one-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `showView` function has to return the same type of view each time, which is why `AnyView` works.

You have a couple of options to fix this:

**Wrap everything in another `View`, e.g. a `Group`**

```
func showView(i: Int) -> some View {
    Group {
        switch  i {
        case 0:
            viewOne
        case 1:
            viewTwo
        default:
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
}
```

**Mark the function with the `@ViewBuilder` attribute**

```
@ViewBuilder
func showView(i: Int) -> some View {
    switch  i {
    case 0:
        viewOne
    case 1:
        viewTwo
    default:
        EmptyView()
    }
}
```